How do I make linear demixing in the spectral domain overdetermined?
Given the spectrum of a mixed signal
$Y(n) = X_1(n)H_1(n) + X_2(n)H_2(n)$
If $X_i$ and $Y$ are known, how do I calculate $H_i$? When I try to put this as a matrix multiplication, the problem is inherently underdetermined (more columns than rows), but if I try to solve this in the time domain using a Toeplitz matrix, the problem is overdetermined, since the Toeplitz matrix has more rows than columns if the filter is shorter than the signal.
$\begin{pmatrix} h_1 \\ h_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} toeplitz(x_1) & toeplitz(x_2) \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \cdot y$
Is there a way to make this problem overdetermined in the spectral domain?

If your $X_i$s are un-correlated, you can use the well known estimate $$H_i = \frac{P_{YX_i}}{P_{X_iX_i}}$$

P here is cpsd? It doesn't really seem to work. the estimate looks nothing like the actual filter spectrum. Is there maybe a guide on how to do this?

Yes, $P$ is the cross power spectral density (in the denominator, the auto power spectral density). This only works if your input signals are completely de-correlated with each other. Are they?

And it only works if the input signals are "spectrally dense", i.e. have sufficient energy at all frequencies to avoid excessive noise amplification, and only if the signals are sufficiently long. This is one of those methods that looks easy on paper but has a LOT of details where things can go side ways (circular vs linear correlation, impulse response aliasing, continuous vs discrete, periodic vs aperiodic etc)

Good point on the spectrally dense requirements @Hilmar.

Your expression denotes that the output is a linear mixture in the time domain and convolutive mixture in the frequency domain. Typically, we deal with the opposite case, so I assuming that $n$ here denotes the frequency bin $f$.
One way of solving this is to use the Wiener filter. We can write:
$Y(f) = \begin{bmatrix} H_1(f) & H_2(f)\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} X_1(f) \\ X_2(f)\end{bmatrix} = H(f)^TX(f)$. We have the observations $Y(f)$, and if we were to write $\hat{Y}(f) = W(f)^TX(f) $. We can minimise:
$$
W^* = \arg \min_W \mathbb{E}((Y - \hat{Y})^2) \\
W^* = \arg\min_W \mathbb{E}((Y - W^TX)^2) \\
W^* = \arg \min_W \mathbb{E}((Y - W^TX)^2) \\
W^* = \arg\min_W \mathbb{E} (Y^2) + \mathbb{E}(W^T X)^2 - 2\mathbb{E}(Y W^TX) \\
W^* = \arg\min_W \mathbb{E} (Y^2) + W^{T}\mathbb{E}(XX^T) W - 2W^T\mathbb{E}(XY) 
$$
Differentiating the cost function wrt the vector $W$ and setting it to 0, we get,
$$
0 = 2 \mathbb{E}(XX^T) W^* - 2 \mathbb{E}(XY) \\
W^* = H = \mathbb{E}(XX^T)^{-1}\mathbb{E}(XY)
$$
Now,
$$
E(XX^T) = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbb{E}(X_1^2) & \mathbb{E}(X_1 X_2) \\
\mathbb{E}(X_2 X_1) & \mathbb{E}(X_2^2) \end{bmatrix}  \\
E(XX^T) = \begin{bmatrix}S_{x_1x_1}(f) & S_{x_1x_2} (f) \\
S_{x_2 x_1} (f) & S_{x_2 x_2}(f) \end{bmatrix} \\
\mathbb{E}(XY) = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbb{E}(X_1 Y) \\ \mathbb{E}(X_2 Y) \end{bmatrix} \\
E(XX^T) = \begin{bmatrix} S_{x_1 y}(f) \\ S_{x_2 y}(f) \end{bmatrix}
$$
Here, $S_{xx}(f)$ is the power spectral density (PSD) of the signal $x$, and $S_{xy}(f)$ is the cross-PSD between the signals $x, y$. These can be calculated from the data using pwelch/welch in Matlab/Python. Or, alternately, by dividing the signal into multiple overlapping frames, windowing them, and averaging their magnitude spectra (see here).

By "across multiple time frames", do you mean, I should chop up the signal into chunks and form X_1, X_2 Y vectors at each frequency?

Yes, the signal is chopped in the time domain with some overlap. Then, each frame is transformed via an FFT and the squared magnitude spectra of the multiple frames are averaged. This is Welch's method for computing the PSD of a signal. I have expanded my answer to clarify this.
